# MongoDB: Unique ID per relationship

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I don't have so much experience with MongoDB so for that I think it's better to try to explain my request through an example.

I have those two entities. The `Tree` has a list of at least one `Leaf` and a `Leaf` can't exists without a `Tree`.

```
data class Tree(
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val leaves: List<Leaf>,
)

data class Leaf(
    val id: UUID,
    val names: List<String>,
)
```

I would like the `id` of the `Leaf` to be `unique` per `Tree`.

For example I can have the first `Tree` document with a `Leaf` which has the `id: 250bb131-2134-5667-0000-000000000000` and another `Tree` can has a `Leaf` with the same `id: 250bb131-2134-5667-0000-000000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to store the Trees and Leafs in a MongoDB given the title of your question.

First, know that MongoDB has no joining, unlike a relational (SQL) database, so you have two choices:

1. **One collection**. You have one Collection with all the Trees in it.

   - **Tree**: If you change the type of `Tree.id` to be `BigInteger` Mongo and leave the value null, Mongo will take care of allocating a unique key*.
   - You need to allocate unique keys yourself for the Leaf objects perhaps by using a Set to ensure you get a unique one
2. **Two collections**. You have two collections one for Leaf and one for Tree.

   - **Tree**: If you change the type of `Tree.id` to be `BigInteger` Mongo and leave the value null, Mongo will take care of allocating a unique key*.
   - **Leaf**: If you change the type of `Leaf.id` to be `BigInteger` Mongo and leave the value null, Mongo will take care of allocating a unique key*.
   - then you have to handle the reference from `Tree.leaves`.  This is all manual - you need change the `leaves` `List` to contain references to the `Leaf` object keys and handle the fetch yourself, e.g. `val leaves: List<BigInteger>,`.  (Mongo does have a [`DBRef`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/DBRef.html) which is no more than an formal reference to database/collection/id)

*Mongo's default key is an `ObjectId` that will serialize into `BigInteger` or you could (pollute?) your code with the `org.bson.types.ObjectId` type.  This class has some useful properties, such as sorting in datetime ascending order.  But more than that you should read how such keys are generated.  Unlike a central RDBMS which is responsible for allocating a lock, issuing a key, and releasing the lock - Mongo's strategy is create the primary key *on the client*.  How could this work safely?  Well: it uses a combination of date time, a client (random) key and an increment (see [spec](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)).  You could this idea yourself in option 1, where you need to guarantee a unique Leaf identifier by using the [`ObjectId` constructor](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java)